# How to prove const char *p is same as char const *p?

Tags: c

How to prove const char *p is same as char const *p through code or memory space model or any other things.
For example, I defined:

```
const char *p;
char const *p;
```

Now from where I can know they take same effect?

Comment: In C++ you could use `typeid`: http://ideone.com/Dlxlh.

Comment: It is a good idea in C++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a matter of style more than anything else.

As for the proof part: They are equivalent because the language rules ensure that both syntax have the *same* semantics. As such, implementations are *required* to make sure that they have the same effect. You may want to read Stroustrup's FAQ item: [Should I put "const" before or after the type?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#constplacement) (though note that C and C++ are different languages, the latter borrowing heavily from the former and to this day does try to maintain compatibility.)

The `const` keyword is an exception in the sense that in this case the C standards committee borrowed something from C++ and retrofitted it to C.

Answer (score 1):

To prove this you look at the standard, best approximation of which you'd find by searching the web for n1570.pdf. There you see that the term `declaration specifiers` is recursively defined, as

```
declaration-specifiers:
type-specifier declaration-specifiers(opt)
type-qualifier declaration-specifiers(opt)
```

(plus other things). From that you deduce that the `type-qualifier` may be written before or after a `type-specifier`.